# Using async with asynchronous functions

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, node-async

I know this sounds stupid, but I can't understand how to use [`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async) to handle existing asynchronous functions.

For example, consider some asynchronous function `foo(arg1, arg2, ..., argN, callback)` defined in some node module. Say I want to use this in `async`'s `waterfall(tasks,[callback])` function. How could I possibly do this?

```
//original call
foo(x1,x2,xN, function goo(err, res) {
    // do something 
});

//using async
async.waterfall([
   function(callback) {
       foo(x1,x2,...,xN, callback);
   }
], function goo(err, res) {
   // do something
});
```

but I can't do that since `callback` needs to be called before the end of the function.
Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup, what you have will work. `callback` just tells async, "I'm done, go to the next". You can also use `async.apply` to generate those little wrapper functions automatically:

```
async.waterfall([
  async.apply(foo, x1, x2, nX) //don't use callback, async will add it,
  someOtherFunction
], function (error, finalResult) {});
```

Comment: Oh ok that works perfectly! I assumed from the documentation that the `callback` had to be invoked before the wrapper function ended

Comment: Nope, it could be 10 layers deep for all async cares. And if it never gets called at all, async will just wait forever.

Comment: Awesome! That **does** make things easy! Thanks for your time